# php, mysql and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to do dynamic select option like when selected dropdown option of first column in database immediately I want to display data of second column from mysql database in input field.

```
<select name="name" class="form-control" autoFocus="" id="clients" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="">Select Client</option>
    <?php 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients");
        while($selectclients = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  
   ?>
    <option id="<?php echo $selectclients['client_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $selectclients['data1'] ?>" onchange="show(this.value);"></option>
   <?php } ?>   
</select>

<span name="data2" type="text" id="data2"></span>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("clients").value;
    document.getElementById("list_currency").innerHTML = "<input name='currency' type=text id='currency' size='12' value="+ x +">";
}
</script>
```

In the script i have used m able to fetch the data and display in dropdown option and when select (first column in database) whatever m selecting in select option m able to display in input field but i m not able to display data from second column of database

I kindly request to help me in this issue

Comment: **Warning**
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: @EliasNicolas - What extension? ;)

Comment: `MySQL_*` functions.

Comment: i thank you for your reply but its not mysqli issue the script which i have shared is working and fetching data from database my issue is that i want to display data from 2 column instead of displaying selected data

Comment: You will need to attach a javascript listener function to the first select menu that sends an ajax query to the db - the callback function of the ajax request then builds the content in the second dropdown menu.

Comment: i have used myFunction in that whatever m selecting in select option m geting so can u help to add javascript function

Comment: In your " while($selectclients = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  " you need to store in some place, maybe a javascript map <client -> 2nd column value>, the second column... then when you choose the client you can show the value from the map. Or you need to do as RamRaider says, do an ajax request to fetch the new data from db.

Comment: I misread the question - I now realiase you do not want to generate content in a secondary dropdown menu - only to display some value in a standard text input field. Is that correct? The value that is to be shown in input field - where is that derived from?

Comment: You really need to read. MySQL_* Are deprecated and remove (in future versions) Use PDO or MySQLi. Do you undertand that? or is it too hard?

Comment: @EliasNicolas don't be desperate. Relax man. There are a lot of reasons why users still preserve `mysql_` functions. The problem in this post is not the mysql connection. Be sure that user read about PDO or MySQLi because he answers you.

Comment: value should be derived from second column of database table

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $query = mysql_query( 'select * from `clients`;' );

    echo "
    <select name='name' class='form-control' autoFocus='' id='clients' onchange='myFunction()'>
        <optgroup label='Select Client'>";
        while( $rs = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ){  
            echo "<option id='{$rs['client_id']}' value='{$rs['data1']}'>{$rs['data1']}</option>";
        }
    echo "  
        </optgroup>
    </select>";
?>


/* span elements do not have a 'type' attribute */
<span name='data2' id='data2'></span>
/* Your original code did not show the receiving html element, list_currency */
<span name='list_currency' id='list_currency'></span>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    function myFunction() {
        var oSelect = document.getElementById('clients');
        var oCur=document.getElementById('list_currency');
        var value=oSelect.options[ oSelect.options.selectedIndex ].value;

        oCur.innerHTML = "<input name='currency' type='text' id='currency' size='12' value=" + value + ">";
    }
</script>
```

I'm not 100% sure I understood the question as there is mention of data from a second column but no reference to it in the code. That said, based on the original when you select an option from the dropdown menu the container element `list_currency` will be populated with the input field with the value of the select menu. If this is NOT what you meant then please explain further - especially what the `second column` is...

Comment: select dropdown will be of clients name(first column) and dispay data will be currency (second column).

Comment: both select client name wil be from mysql database (first column) and display currency also will be of same datable table (second column)

Comment: in the code posted by RamRaider is also display same data of select option in input field, where as m looking is that other data from second column from database should display

Answer (score 0):

the above post of code is working good as per my requirement after small modification

```html
<?php 
    $query = mysql_query( 'select * from `clients`;' );

    echo "
    <select name='name' class='form-control' autoFocus='' id='clients' onchange='myFunction()'>
        <optgroup label='Select Client'>";
        while( $rs = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ){  
            echo "<option id='{$rs['client_id']}' value='{$rs['currency']}'>{$rs['name']}</option>";
        }
    echo "  
        </optgroup>
    </select>";
?>



<span name='list_currency' id='list_currency'></span>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    function myFunction() {
        var oSelect = document.getElementById('clients');
        var oCur=document.getElementById('list_currency');
        var value=oSelect.options[ oSelect.options.selectedIndex ].value;

        oCur.innerHTML = "<input name='currency' type='text' id='currency' size='12' value=" + value + ">";
    }
</script>
```

I thanks a lot for posting this code thank you soo much

Comment: oh ho sorry the below answer is working fine only when displayed but i want to post those two data in another table

Comment: if i post both data in two different column it is same data in first column and in second column

Comment: request you to help me in ths issue

Comment: while displaying its correct as per requirement but while post both data in mysql should get post in 2 different column